# Concatenating files in multiple directories from batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd, xcopy

I'm trying to concatenate files from multiple directories. From a single directory, I know that you can execute

```
copy /B *.blah all.blah
```

to concatenate the files with extension `.blah` to a single file named `all.blah`. What my structure looks like is:

```
level 1/
    level 2_1/
        file_1.blah
        file_2.blah
    level 2_2/
        ...
    level 2_3/
        ...
    do_not_include_this_directory/
        ...
```

What I'm looking to do is create a single `all.blah` file in the top level directory which is a concatenation of all the `.blah` files in the `level*` sub-directories, without including any files from the `do_not_include_this_directory` directory.

My aim is to do this in a batch file (there will be other file concatenation logic for different directories included in this batch file), but I've spent the hour past playing around with `cmd for` logic to no avail (some of my directories have spaces in the names). Maybe this is something that I should just do using a python script? I'm thinking that this can be done relatively easily though using some `for` loops with `copy`, but my skills with these things are lacking to say the least (just came across cmd for about 2 hours ago).

Does anyone know how to do this, or would you just recommend that I buck up and write something using Python? Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done easily from the command line without a batch script :)

```
copy nul all.blah >nul&for /d %F in (level*) do @copy /b all.blah + "%F\*.blah" >nul
```

As a batch script

```
@echo off
copy nul all.blah >nul
for /d %F in (level*) do copy /b all.blah + "%F\*.blah" >nul
```

I'm not sure if the `/B` switch is exactly correct. It has different meaning depending on where it appears: before any file, after a source, or after the destination.

Comment: Indeed, they've specified multiple positions for `[/A | /B]` in the built-in help. Perhaps, specifying the option before all the files should imply that all of them are (to be treated as) binary files. Do you know for certain whether that is so?

Comment: @AndriyM - I suspect that to be the case, but I'm not sure.

Comment: I still have the issue of ignoring the "do not include..." directory, but it's because I didn't explain my situation well. How do you skip a directory with a similar name. AKA I want directories that start with "level 0xxxx" (x is some digit), ignoring any other directories (including ones like "level Axxxx" (x is anything)? If you need more clarification I can edit my question.

Comment: @JesseBuesking: Extend the `level*` mask to `"level 0*"`, perhaps? or maybe to `"level 0????"`?

Answer (score 0):

This seems suitably horrific for a Windows batch file. Tested under Windows 7; YMMV, etc.

```
@rem get all pathnames, even in excluded directories
@rem EDIT THIS COMMAND to change wildcard to match
dir /b/s *.c >files.tmp
@rem get rid of things with prefix we want to exclude
@rem EDIT THIS COMMAND to change prefix
findstr /V "C:\temp\fee" files.tmp >files2.tmp
del copy.tmp
@rem append things one at a time the hard way!
For /f tokens^=*^ delims^=^ eol^=  %%a in (files2.tmp) do (
copy "%%a" + copy.tmp copy2.tmp
del copy.tmp
rename copy2.tmp copy.tmp
echo.%%a)
@rem clean up
del copy2.tmp
del files.tmp
del files2.tmp
```